How to prove that $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{m!}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{mn}e^{-2^n}=0$.
Through rough calculations, we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{mn}e^{-2^n}=2^m\int_{0}^{\infty}2^{mx}e^{-2^x}dx=\frac{2^m}{\log 2}\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{m-1}e^{-t}dt\leq \frac{2^m\Gamma(m)}{\log 2}.
$$
It follows that $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{m!}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{mn}e^{-2^n}\leq \lim\limits_{m\to\infty} \frac{1}{m!}\cdot\frac{2^m\;\Gamma(m)}{\log 2}=\infty$, which is not the estimation we desired.
We conjecture that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{mn}e^{-2^n}\leq C \int_{0}^{\infty}2^{mx}e^{-2^x}dx,\quad\qquad(1)$$
where the constant $C$ is independent of $m$. Unfortunately, we are unable to prove it. Clearly,
if (1) holds true, it is evident that the desired limit $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{m!}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{mn}e^{-2^n}=0$.

The conclusion stands valid even without the necessity to establish formula (1).
Note that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{mn}e^{-2^n}<\int_{0}^{\infty}2^{mx}e^{-2^x}dx+2\max\{2^{mx}e^{-2^x}\}<\frac{\Gamma(m)}{\log 2}+2m^m e^{-m}.
$$
Thus, by using Stirling's formula $m! \approx \sqrt{2\pi m} \left(\frac{m}{e}\right)^m$, we have, when $m\to\infty$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{m!}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{mn}e^{-2^n}&\leq
\frac{1}{m!}\frac{\Gamma(m)}{\log 2}+\left(\sqrt{2\pi m}(\frac{m}{e})^m\right)^{-1}\cdot 2m^m e^{-m}\\
&=\frac{1}{m\log 2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi m}}\to 0.
\end{align*}

We can switch from summation to integration indeed. Using the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula
$$S(m)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{mn}e^{-2^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{mn}e^{-2^n}-e^{-1}\sim\int_0^\infty e^{m\ln(2)x-e^{\ln(2)x}}dx-\frac12e^{-1}+\,\text{derivatives}$$
According to the formula, we take derivatives on the bounds, what gives us the terms $\sim m^k,\,k=1,\,2,\,...$, and we will see that they are exponentially small compared to the integral.
As for the integral - we can evaluate it at $m\to\infty$ by means of Laplace' method. Making the substitution $t=e^{\ln(2)x};\,x=\frac{\ln t}{\ln2}$
$$I(m)=\int_0^\infty e^{m\ln(2)x-e^{\ln(2)x}}dx=\frac1{\ln2}\int_1^\infty e^{m\ln t-t}\frac{dt}t\overset{t=mx}{=}\frac{m^m}{\ln2}\int_{\frac1m}^\infty e^{-m(x-\ln x)}\frac{dx}x$$
The function $f(x)=x-\ln x$ reaches its minimum at the point $x=1$ on the interval $[1/m;\,\infty)$
$$f'(x)=1-\frac1x;\,f''(1)=1$$
Therefore,
$$I(m)\sim\frac{m^me^{-m}}{\ln2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{mt^2}2}dt=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\ln2}m^{m-\frac12}e^{-m}$$
Evaluating next asymptotic term one can show that
$$I(m)=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\ln2}\left(\frac me\right)^m\frac1{\sqrt m}\left(1+O\Big(\frac1m\Big)\right)$$
It follows that our sum
$$S(m)=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\ln2}\left(\frac me\right)^m\frac1{\sqrt m}\left(1+O\Big(\frac1m\Big)\right)$$
Given that $\,\,\displaystyle m!=\sqrt{2\pi m}\left(\frac me\right)^m\left(1+O\Big(\frac1m\Big)\right)$
$$\frac{S(m)}{m!}=\frac1{\ln(2)m}\left(1+O\Big(\frac1m\Big)\right)\to0\,\,\text{at}\,\,m\to\infty$$
